# Unknown display

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I recently acquired myself another display for my computer, unfortunate it had VGA access and my computer only supports DVI. So I bought a converter from VGA to DVI.
My problem now is that, when I open System Settings > Displays, it looks like this:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone could help me. I have tried to search around for solutions, but so far none of them seems to be quite the same problem.

Oh, I forgot to mention that my unknown display is http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EZD3KYQ/ref=pe_385721_51767431_TE_dp_1 .

Answer (score 0):

- I had similar problems with Ubuntu 12.04 & EliteBook 8530w.
- External display didn't work.
- I changed display driver to a newer version and it helped.
- System Settings -> Additional Drivers.

Comment: I tried doing what you told me, but so far no luck.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/hdWRE.png